# PHP data fetch script working in localhost but not working in hosting with ssl

Tags: php, curl

i want to fetch data from user input url. i tried in localhost it is working but when uploaded to hosting it is not working.
Please help regarding this.

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
//browser's user agent string (UA) 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.47 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;}
//Checking for the json data in fetched content
$pattern = '/window._sharedData = (.*) /';
preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches);

//checking if we got the data or not
if(!$matches){
$response['status'] = 'fail';   
echo json_encode($response);
exit; }
//getting json from content
$json = $matches[1];
//decoding json to process
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: "not working" isn't a useful description. There could be several different problems potentially. Check the PHP error log file on the server and see if you get any clues.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check that Curl is installed or not to php on your server.

Run following line in your index php file.

```
curl_getinfo($ch)
```

If ıt'not installed, then import curl.